# In website filters, is it correct to include "ago" in, for example, "Earlier than one year ago"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

On one of the websites I have recently visited, it allowed me to filter the articles published by month/year. The wordings were something like this,

Earlier than one year ago (29000)
one year ago - one month ago (1500)
one month ago - one week ago (4)
one week ago - today (1)
today (2)

Bracket has the number of articles in that filter. I am not sure if this the correct wording.

Especially the *Earlier than one year **ago***. Can anyone confirm if the use of the word ago is correct here?

Comment: I would use “***more** than one year ago*”

Comment: "Ago" seems necessary for those constructions.

Comment: Why do you think that this usage of "ago" is incorrect?

Comment: @Jim But that would be a measure of time passed rather than a position prior to a specific point. Moreover, it might lead to misunderstanding, *e.g.*, 'more than one year ago' could understood as 'at least two years ago'; and the adamantine law of written English is that *Anything which **can** be misunderstood **will** be.*

Comment: @StoneyB - interesting.  “More than a year ago” sounds perfectly right to me while “earlier than a year ago” sounds off somehow.  I think it has to do with the other choices being a measure of time rather than a point in time.  1 day ago, 1 week ago, 1 year ago, more than 1 year ago.

Comment: @Catija the correct words according to me were "Earlier than one year". I didn't see a reason to add "ago" in there. But I wanted to know why ago was added. English is my second language so sometimes I get confused over use of certain words.. Just getting a clarification.

Comment: That's fine, of course... sometimes it's helpful to know why you think something in your question because it gives the person/people answering the opportunity to directly explain why that feeling is wrong. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One year ago* is a point in time, just like *now* or *at six o'clock*; and just as you can say *earlier than now* or *earlier than six o'clock* you can say *earlier than [one year ago]*

Think of it like this:

```
                                           [one year ago]                now
                                                  ↓                       ↓
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - *
← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ← earlier than [1 year ago] ← ↵
```